# Extract numbers from an Array which has more than one string element

Tags: python, filter, numbers

An array has 4 elements. I want only the the **thousands** to printed out.

```
my_array = ['STK72184 4/28/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 50 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus 5000 Regular 10/20/2023 Approved 4/28/2022',
            'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 5000 Regular 10/19/2023 Approved 4/27/2022',
            'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 15000 Regular 10/19/2023 Approved 4/27/2022',
            'STK722222 4/26/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 10000 Regular 10/18/2023 Approved 4/26/2022']
```

Expected output is:

```
[‘5000’, ‘5000’, ‘15000’, ‘10000’]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: @TimurShtatland than you for the help :) Will do it.

Comment: Please remember to vote on the answers and accept the best solution. See also: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), which extract the first match to the pattern of 1 or more digit, followed by 3 zeros.

```
import re

my_array = ['STK72184 4/28/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 50 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus 5000 Regular 10/20/2023 Approved 4/28/2022',
            'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 5000 Regular 10/19/2023 Approved 4/27/2022',
            'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 15000 Regular 10/19/2023 Approved 4/27/2022',
            'STK722222 4/26/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 10000 Regular 10/18/2023 Approved 4/26/2022']

# If you want strings:
nums = [re.search(r'\d+000', s)[0] for s in my_array]
print(nums)
# ['5000', '5000', '15000', '10000']

# If you want integers:
nums = [int(re.search(r'\d+000', s)[0]) for s in my_array]
print(nums)
# [5000, 5000, 15000, 10000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lines = [l.split() for l in my_array] 
[w for words in lines for w in words if w.isnumeric() and int(w) > 1000]
```

```
['5000', '5000', '15000', '10000']
```

Answer (score 0):

you could map a function that, splits the first the string and taking the item in the array that you want, in this case:

```
>>> array = ['STK72184 4/28/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 50 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus 5000 Regular 10/20/2023 Approved 4/28/2022',
...     'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 5000 Regular 10/19/2023 Approved 4/27/2022',
...     'STK725721 4/27/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 15000 Regular 10/19/2023 Approved 4/27/2022',
...     'STK722222 4/26/2022 50 from Exchange Balance, 40 from Earning Balance & 10 from Bonus Balance 10000 Regular 10/18/2023 Approved 4/26/2022']
>>> #mapping with the function
>>> thousands = list(map(lambda x:x.split()[-5],array))
>>> thousands
['5000', '5000', '15000', '10000']
```